# Does AWS CloudFormation support ECS Task Placement strategies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cloudformation

Does AWS CloudFormation support ECS Task Placement strategies?

I am hoping it is just not well-documented. It looks like it is only possible via the AWS CLI and the AWS Console.

If not supported, anyone know the timeline?

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: What do you mean by ECS task placement strategies?

Comment: @ManishJoshi, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-placement-strategies.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes**, as of [Apr 28 2017](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/04/aws-cloudformation-adds-support-for-amazon-cognito-ebs-elastic-volumes-and-updates-resource-coverage/), CloudFormation supports ECS Task Placement strategies, via the [`PlacementStrategies`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-service.html#cfn-ecs-service-placementstrategies) Property on the [`AWS::ECS::Service`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-service.html) Resource.

---

Previous answer (1/19/2017) below:

No, it appears that AWS CloudFormation's official resources do not currently support ECS Task Placement strategies.

The CloudFormation Resource corresponding to the ECS [`CreateService`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_CreateService.html) API is [`AWS::ECS::Service`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-service.html), which does not have a Property corresponding to `CreateService`'s [`placementStrategy`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_CreateService.html#ECS-CreateService-request-placementStrategy) request parameter.

There is typically a lag between the introduction of new AWS product features and their support in AWS CloudFormation. ECS Task Placement was only just released on [Dec 29 2016](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/12/introducing-amazon-ecs-task-placement-policies/), while the ECS CloudFormation resources were only last updated in [January 2016](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-supported-resources.html).

If you can't wait for official CloudFormation support for this new feature parameter, you could implement creating/deleting an ECS service as a [Custom Resource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) that calls the `CreateService`/[`DeleteService`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteService.html) APIs directly, e.g., in a Lambda function using the AWS SDK for NodeJS.

Comment: does it use `az spread` by default? Or must this be explicitly defined in CFN?

Comment: `PlacementStrategies` Property is optional (`Required: No`), so it doesn't need to be explicitly defined. For optional CFn parameters in general, look to the API definition for the default behavior- in this case ([`CreateService`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_CreateService.html)), the documentation says: "By default, the service scheduler attempts to balance tasks across Availability Zones in this manner [...]" - so it does not explicitly say the default behavior is _identical_ to `az spread`, but it sounds similar.